# Trying to delete task in airflow causes mushroom cloud error

Tags: airflow

Using airflow v1.9.0. Trying to set task state to `failed` for a task that is taking too long (the task itself is running a `sqoop` command to get data from another DB, if that may be relevant). When trying to set the state of the task to `failed` via the webserver UI, I get the mushroom cloud error page and the error trace below.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 2068, in action_view
    return self.handle_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/actions.py", line 113, in handle_action
    response = handler[0](ids)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 2498, in action_set_failed
    self.set_task_instance_state(ids, State.FAILED)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 2540, in set_task_instance_state
    raise Exception("Ooops")
Exception: Ooops
```

Happens both for tasks that are running or queued to run.

Not sure what to make of this. Anyone with more airflow experience have any further debugging tips or know how to fix this? Any other info that should be added to this question for debugging?